# I compiled PHP with a bunch of extensions and I can't find any of the .so files

Tags: php, compilation, devops, php-7.2

I had to remake my PHP cookbook and, while it's got to be awfully close to the original, when I `make install`, the only .so files I get (ie the contents of `/usr/lib64/php/modules` on Centos 7) are `opcache.so` and `opcache.a`. There are a bunch of extensions in the configure options, and `php -i` seems to think they should all be there, but `find / -name mbstring.so` and `find / curl.so`, for example, find nothing.

**Update**

My configure command looks like `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-mbstring --with-curl`

And it should look like `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-mbstring=shared --with-curl=shared`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get `.so` files for modules that you configured with the `shared` tag:

```
./configure --with-pspell=shared --with-gettext=shared --with-gd=shared
```

If you just do this:

```
./configure --with-pspell --with-gettext --with-gd
```

Then the modules will be baked into the main PHP binary.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Hey, we also have Chef Compliance running with CIS benchmarks thanks to you guys!